# Как внести в кортеж неограниченное кол-во чисел/слов?

Tags: python, список

Задача:
Записать N произвольных чисел, и вывести на экран наибольшее из них.
Хочу сделать такую конструкцию:

```
list = []
print(max(list))
```

При этом, список заполнить числами через пробел или запятую. Как это реализовать?

Comment: почему-то не отображается перенос строки между list = [] и print(max(list)), но я думаю вы поняли суть вопроса :)

Comment: `list = [int(i) for i in input().split()]` - ввод целых чисел в одну строку через пробел

Answer (score 1):

- У вас список, а не кортеж
- Не используйте для названий переменных зарезервированные слова питона, например, `list`

Вот вам два варианта - через запятую заданные через программу числа и через пробел введённые пользователем:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(max(lst))

lst = list(map(int, input('введите числа через пробелы').split()))
print(max(lst))
```